# Set background image in thymleaf with dynamic url

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to show a background image in thymleaf which url is coming from backend spring boot

```
<div class="card-img-top" th:style="background-image:url(/assets/img/banner-anout.jpg)" > </div>
```

This is the element 
I want to fill it with a variable like

```
<div class="card-img-top" th:style="background-image:url(${product.image})" > </div>
```

I tried with several approach like below

```
<div class="card-img-top" th:style="background: url{[[@{${product.image}]]}" > </div>
```

But it does not work.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the string you need by concatenating the literal parts with the Thymeleaf expression:

```
<div class="card-img-top" 
     th:style="'background-image:url(' + ${product.image}+ ')'" >
</div>
```